# Ingoing / Outgoing Email downloading and processing, Server Side

Tags: php, linux, email, centos

Basically I've been asked if there is any way that I can capture & download all incoming and outgoing emails ( preferably in text format ) going through a mail server. This downloading method needs to be done using PHP or similar server side language.

If I can pass the above stage, then the final goal is easily reachable, which is to allow me process the emails via a script of some sort.

If there is any sort of mediating RPM I can install that would allow me to port emails to a directory somewhere, could also be of great help.

I am completely lost on where to start with this, so any sort of pointers or advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks 
Scott

More Info : 
 Server      : **CentOS** 
Mail Server : **Pop3**

Answer (score 0):

"Downloading" email is the same is fetching email. Have a look at the [PHP IMAP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php).
Plenty of examples there to get you going.